# Multiple checkbox-forms with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm new to angularjs / ionic and I try to create an ionic-app that posts IDs of prodcuts to a webserver. I have to display multiple `<form>` on one page with checkboxes (..and other types like select). 
When I submit the first form everything works as expected. But when I try to submit a second form, the scope contains values from the first and from the second form. When i submit an empty form it also submits the values from the first form. Is there a way to "clean" the scope after every submit? How can I assure that the submit-button only submits values from its own form?

This is the `<form>` :

```
<form ng-submit="addCartFive()" name="type5_{{item.ID}}">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col col-80"><strong>{{item['name']}}</strong> <br/>
                               {{item['description']}}
    </div>
  </div>
  <div ng-repeat="variant in item.variants">
    <ion-list ng-repeat="detail in variant.details">
        <ion-checkbox name="sub-{{$index}}" ng-true-value="{{detail.ID}}" ng-model="formDataObjFive[$index][detail.ID]">
        {{detail.name}} <span class="right">+ {{detail.price}}</span>
      </ion-checkbox>
    </ion-list>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
      <button type="submit" ng-click="setValueFive(formDataObjFive)">order</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

this is the relevant part of my controller:

```
  $scope.setValueFive = function(a1) {
    $scope.formDataObjFive = a1;
  };

  $scope.addCartFive = function () {
    console.log($scope.formDataObjFive);
    CartService.save($scope.formDataObjFive) // send the values to factory wich posts to server
  };
```

Comment: **HTML:** `<form ng-submit="addCartFive(item.ID)" name="type5_{{item.ID}}">` **Controller**: `$scope.addCartFive = function () { $scope.type5_[item.ID] = {}; }`

Comment: It shows this error: ReferenceError: item is not defined.

Do i have to change something in the ng-model of the ion-checkbox?